# How to position a label text at the outside end of horizontal bar graph (ggplot) when label is unrelated to fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataset that looks like the following below. I am making a horizontal bar chart with ggplot that plots number of students (filled by status) but I want the label (the total students who completed the work to be at the end of the bar so you can see the total n but also % completed. I have the code I am currently using. I'm trying to figure out how to do hjust based on the rate rather then the number of students. Do I need to adjust the dataframe with new info or different info to make this easier or can I use something with hjust to put the label at the outside end of the bar chart?

```
   State      Number of Students Rate Denominator Status        Label
1     CT                   4500 0.471        8500 Completed     47.1%
2     CT                   4000 0.471        8500 Not Completed <NA>
3     OK                   4375 0.653        6700 Completed     65.3%
4     OK                   2325 0.653        6700 Not Completed <NA>
5     TX                   5040 0.70         7200 Completed     70.0%
6     TX                   2160 0.70         7200 Not Completed <NA>

ec <- ggplot(data, aes(y=reorder(State, Rate), x= `Number of Students`, fill = Status)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  ggtitle("Completed Rates by State")+
  ylab("State") +
  geom_text(aes(label=label))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(state = c('CT', 'CT', 
                           'OK', 'OK', 
                           'TX', 'TX'), 
           numberOfStudents = c(4500, 4000, 
                                4375, 2325, 
                                5040, 2160), 
           denominator =  c(8500, 8500,
                            6700, 7600, 
                            7200, 7200), 
           rate = c( 0.471, 
                     0.471, 
                     0.653, 
                     0.653, 
                     0.70, 0.70),
           status = c('Completed', 'Not Completed', 
                      'Completed','Not Completed', 
                      'Completed', 'Not Completed'), 
           label = c('47.1%',  NA, '65.3%', NA, '70.0%', NA)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, 
           mapping = aes(y=reorder(state, rate), 
                         x= numberOfStudents, 
                         fill = status), 
           stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  ggtitle("Completed Rates by State")+
  ylab("State") +
  xlim(0, 9000)+
  geom_text(data = df, 
            mapping = aes(y = state, 
                          x = denominator, 
                          label=label), 
            hjust = 0)
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Hi! I am getting this error: Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: Here's the Code - am I missing something?  ec <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, 
           mapping = aes(y=reorder(State, Rate), 
                         x=`Number of Students`, 
                         fill = Status),stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  ggtitle("Completed Rates by State")+
  ylab("State") +
  geom_text(data = df, 
            mapping = aes(y = State, 
                          x = Denominator, 
                          label=label), 
            hjust = 0)

Comment: jk figured it out! Thanks this worked!